# What do I do if my dog inhaled dog shampoo?

Tags: dogs, health, safety, eating, poison

My dog inhaled dog shampoo, at first she was making noises, but over time they started disappearing. But now she makes tiny little noises from time to time; it's been 4-5 hours since that incident, will she be okay? She is a small dog and only 12-13 weeks old.

edit:She is now making sounds like shes snoring she would stop for a minute or 30 seconds but start doing it again. Does this mean she is getting better?

Comment: Have you called your vet? That should always be the first step.

Comment: Probably not too big of a concern as dog shampoo are usually safe for dogs because it's so easy to get it in their mouth or nose. It would be great if you can clean it out with some kind of a sinus cleaner like for humans(saw it in an informercial). You should just call your vets and ask them, I am sure if they are decent human beings they would just tell you it is ok or not

Answer (score 1):

You should always call the vet and have them speak to you about the situation. If she is not vomiting and is acting normally/going potty okay, I would recommend giving her some white rice with chicken broth. Make sure the chicken broth does not have any added salt or preservatives. This should soothe her stomach.